# box-sizing - 'outline' is calculated in 'border-box' OR 'content-box'?

Tags: css, border-box, box-sizing

When calculating width and height of the box, outline width like

```
outline: 5px dashed red;
```

if `box-sizing:border-box`, is outline will be considered in the width/height of the box ?

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a note about it on W3Schools [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)

It says: "Outline differs from borders! Unlike border, the outline is drawn outside the element's border, and may overlap other content. Also, the outline is NOT a part of the element's dimensions; the element's total width and height is not affected by the width of the outline."

When you set an outline it should NOT be affected by `box-sizing` setting and outline will be outside of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Outline property is independent of box-sizing and is not as part of width or height of the element. I generally used to stand out the element from the crowd.